# How to generate random data for testing database performance?

Tags: mysql, testing

I have created a test table in MySQL and would like to insert 10 million rows with randomly generated data. How to do this random generation process? Is there any predefined method in MySQL or is there any quick query we can construct to do this job?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On MySQL forge: [RandomDataGenerator](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/RandomDataGenerator):

> The Random Data Generator allows the creation of tables of arbitary
>   size containing an arbitary combination of columns, filled with random
>   data.

Answer (score 2):

You might also like the Large Data Generator (ldg) script from Tungsten's toolbox, useful for larger datasets.

Download: http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-toolbox/downloads/list

Docs:     http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-toolbox/wiki/Large_Data_generator

Answer (score 1):

This one is as easy as:

```
call procedurename('DATABASE','TABLE',1000,'');
```

will fill 1000 random rows.

Here is the stored procedure to [generate random test data](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-random-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines).

Comment: I wonder why this was edited too. I had a look at the previous revision and visited that URL. I found some useful MySQL functions there.

Comment: @Batandwa there I updated the answer .. You have your procedure now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com) which seems very customisable. You can also create an account on the website to store your configuration by donating or fork the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/benkeen/generatedata) and install it locally.

An alternative is [databasetestdata.com](http://www.databasetestdata.com/). It doesn't seem as customisable generatedata.com, but does a pretty good job. You can also store and reuse your fields layouts (aka recipes).

I would recommend downloading the data as CSV and using [`MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to import the data into your database.